# Function using switch not returning the desired value

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, and I've having some trouble with this particular code. It is supposed to be a Rock, Paper, Scissors using the switch statement, but it's not returning the draw value and is returning other values wrong:

```
function RPS(ch1, ch2){
    switch (ch1, ch2){
        case ('r' && 'p') || ('p' && 'r'):
            return 'p';
            break;

        case ('r' && 's') || ('s' && 'r'):
            return 'r';
            break;

        case ('p' && 's') || ('s' && 'p'):
            return 's';
            break;

        default:
            return 'draw';

    }
}

console.log(RPS('s', 's'));
```

So testing with 's' and 's', I was expecting 'draw' but it returned 'r'. What did I do wrong?

Comment: [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), [Switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) (And what do you think something like `'p' && 's'` evaluates to? You can try it in the console.) Work in smaller chunks, test your assumptions, and don't make up ideas about "should" be happening--test it.

Comment: I'd probably also rephrase to "it's returning other values wrong" to "it's not returning the values I expect"; it's doing exactly what it's written to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are mistakes of your code.

- You can't have two variables for switch statement. `ch1, ch2` will evaluate to `ch2`.
- `'r' && 'p'` will always evaluate to `true`. Because both `r` and `p` are truthy values.

You can do that in following steps:

- Create an object with keys as return values `p,q,r`. And their values will be the array of two values for which you want to checking in the original code. For example `p` will have array `['r','p']`
- You `Object.entries` on the object. And use `find()` on entries.
- Inside `find()` put the values `ch1` and `ch2` in array in both order i.e `[ch1,ch2]` and `[ch2,ch1]`
- Check if any of the array is equal to any of value of object using `every()`
- If yes then return the key otherwise return `'draw'`

```js
function RPS(ch1, ch2){
    
    const obj = {
      p:['r','p'],
      r:['r','s'],
      q:['p','s']
    }
    let entry = Object.entries(obj)
                    .find(([k,v]) =>
                        [ch1,ch2].every((x,i) => x === v[i]) || 
                        [ch2,ch1].every((x,i) => x === v[i])
                    )
    return entry ? entry[0] : 'draw';
}

console.log(RPS('s','p'))
```